# If Statement within Linq Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I am attempting to sort dropdownlist just exactly how it is entered in the database only if a specific id is selected. Otherwise I want them to sorted in ascending order. I was not sure how to add the final component of not sorting the list when a particular Id is selected. Here is where i am so far:

```
var items = (from p in _db.Funds
                     where p.DesignationId == id
                     orderby p.Name ascending 
                     select new { p.id, p.Name });
        return items;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "exactly how it is entered in the database"? You should regard rows in a database table as unordered unless you specify an ordering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
var items = 
    (from p in _db.Funds
     where p.DesignationId == id
     select new { p.id, p.Name });
if (id != "some id")
{
    items = items.OrderBy(p => p.Name);
}

return items.ToList();
```

Comment: Just remember to call `ToList()` method to execute your query.

Comment: p.DesignationId is the Id i wanted it to be based on

Comment: This works but wouldn't it perform better if you determined the ordering before hand and made it so `orderby` is part of the LINQ to SQL query rather than a LINQ to Objects query done after?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal The ordering *will* be executed as a Linq-to-SQL / -Entities query.

Comment: @Paradigm So... if no `id` is selected display everything unordered; if some `id` is selected just display those items, ordered by `Name`. Is that right?

Comment: @p.s.w.g interesting.. I would have expected it be run on an `IEnumerable<AnonymousType>` that gets returned by the original query... I'll take your word for it though as I haven't tinkered with that much.

Comment: The original query will return `IQueryable<T>`, so when you call `OrderBy`, it basically just adds that to the SQL query that will run whenever you enumerate the results. That's part of the power of Linq. :)

Comment: Well if "some id" is selected then unordered otherwise order. This is actually just an ajax that my jquery is calling

Comment: @Paradigm Easy enough. See my updated answer. If it still doesn't meet your needs, please update your question to include the expected results in each case.

Answer (score 2):

It would be a solution

```
var items = (from p in _db.Funds
                 where p.DesignationId == id
                 orderby p.id == "the id" ? p.Name : null 
                 select new { p.id, p.Name });
return items;
```